# Audio mixer, one output to multiple inputs

Tags: audio, bluetooth, mixer

I'm trying to create a device that will take one stereo input and send it to 4 or more audio Bluetooth transmitters. This way, I can connect my prjoector to it and everyone watching can listen in on bluetooth earbuds. I have the Bluetooth devices, they are all identical. Is it OK to connect all the left (and right) inputs and output together directly, or should I isolate them with capacitors? I don't need to adust the volume at each one as that can be done at the earbuds.
Thanks!

Comment: So you really want an audio _splitter_, not a _mixer_...

Comment: Please provide data sheet links for the Bluetooth devices and explain how each Bluetooth device receives its power.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but since you are sending the sound via Bluetooth, it's digitized? I think many PC software could do that quite easily. Splitting an audio signal in four will lead to a very weak audio signal.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. So I suppose I do need an audio splitter. The bluetooth devices are under $10, from China, and have no datasheets. Powered by 5V, all have common power, including ground. A PC isn't involved in any of this, just plain old analog audio, going to Bluetooth 'Transmitters', which go to Bluetooth earbuds.